# Django Channels ASGI - AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet

Tags: django, django-channels, daphne, uvicorn, asgi

Running my project with `python manage.py runserver` boots it up perfectly using the channels asgi development server, however when running the project with Daphne (`daphne project.routing:application`) I get the error `AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet`.

`settings.py`

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'channels',
    'whitenoise.runserver_nostatic',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    # ...
    # ... installed apps and custom apps
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'project.wsgi.application'

ASGI_APPLICATION = 'project.routing.application'

CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
        'CONFIG': {
            "hosts": [REDIS_URL],
        }
    },
}
```

`routing.py`

```py
import os

from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter

from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
from django.conf.urls import url

from my_app.consumers import MyCustomConsumer

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "project.settings")

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    "http": get_asgi_application(),
    'websocket': AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter([
            url(r'^ws/custom/$', MyCustomConsumer),
        ])
    ),
})
```

I have tried adding `django.setup()` as described in other questions, as well as running with `uvicorn` instead of `daphne` but still getting the same error. I've also tried pointing to the websocket routing in `settings.CHANNEL_LAYERS['ROUTING']` and moving the application initialization out to an `asgi.py` file but no luck there either. I can't tell what I'm doing differently from the channels documentation, any help appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django apps aren't loaded yet when using asgi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53683806/django-apps-arent-loaded-yet-when-using-asgi)

Answer (score 11):

Fetch Django ASGI application early to ensure AppRegistry is populated
before importing consumers and AuthMiddlewareStack that may import ORM
models.

```
import os
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "project.settings")
django_asgi_app = get_asgi_application()

from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter

from my_app.consumers import MyConsumer

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
# Django's ASGI application to handle traditional HTTP requests
"http": django_asgi_app,
# WebSocket chat handler
"websocket": AuthMiddlewareStack(
    URLRouter([
        path('ws/custom/', MyConsumer),
    ])
),
```

})

Comment: After trying this, the following error showed up:
```TypeError asgiref.compatibility in new_application

__call__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'send'```

Answer (score 2):

asgi.py

```
import os
import django

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'chat.settings')
django.setup()

from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from chat import routing

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    'http': get_asgi_application(),
    "websocket": AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            routing.websocket_urlpatterns
       )
    )
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Nothing worked for me mentioned above. But i tried with below configuration for working in local machine:

```
import os
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'app.settings')
django_asgi_app = get_asgi_application()

from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from app.tokenAuthMiddleware import TokenAuthMiddleware
from app.routing import channel_routing

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    "http": django_asgi_app,
    "websocket": TokenAuthMiddleware(
     URLRouter(channel_routing)
    )
})
```

And then run the below command:

```
gunicorn app.asgi:application -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornH11Worker
```

Using `UvicornH11Worker` instead of `UvicornWorker` worked for me.

You can check the below link for its reference:
[uvicorn running with gunicorn](https://www.uvicorn.org/#running-with-gunicorn)

Answer (score 0):

The problem arose from pointing the daphne server at the application in `routing.py`, when instead it needs to point at an `asgi.py` file. However, within `settings.py`, `ASGI_APPLICATION` needs to point at the application in the `routing.py` file.

asgi.py

```py
import os
import django
from channels.routing import get_default_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "project.settings")
django.setup()
application = get_default_application()
```

settings.py

```py
ASGI_APPLICATION = 'project.routing.application'
```

routing.py

```py
import os

from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from django.urls import path

from my_app.consumers import MyConsumer


application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    'websocket': AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter([
            path('ws/custom/', MyConsumer),
        ])
    ),
})
```

Then running the daphne server with `daphne project.asgi:application`