# Django - How can my asgi websocket path be on my swagger

Tags: django, swagger, ws, drf-yasg

I am creating an api where two endpoints are using the ws(s) protocol.
As my API is behind Google endpoint, Every endpoint needs to be defined onto an OpenApi2.0 file.

To create this definition I use drf-yasg.

I have a routing. py file like this:

```
""" systems/routing.py"""
from django.urls import path

from .consumers.list_sessions_consumer import MyFirstConsumer
from .consumers.session_consumer import MySecondConsumer

urlpatterns = [
    path(r'v1/ws/yo/<str:uuid>/sessions-sumpup', MyFirstConsumer.as_asgi()),
    path(r'v1/ws/yo/<str:uuid>/sessions', MySecondConsumer.as_asgi()),
]
```

and I register it onto my asgi.py file like this:

```
# pylint: skip-file
""" main/asgi.py """
import os
import django

from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
django_asgi_app = get_asgi_application()


os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'main.settings')
django.setup()

from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from systems.websockets.routing import urlpatterns as system_websocket_url

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    "http": django_asgi_app,
    "websocket": AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            system_websocket_url
        )
    ),
})
```

Don't mind the import order this is due to this error: [Django apps aren't loaded yet when using asgi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53683806/django-apps-arent-loaded-yet-when-using-asgi)

So my socket works as expected, now, I want my command line: **python3 manage.py generate_swagger swagger.yaml** to add these new endpoint to my swagger file.

I tried to directly add my url to the same object then all my other urls like so:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path(r'v1/toto/<str:uuid>', MyView.as_view()),
    ...,
    path(r'v1/ws/yo/<str:uuid>/sessions-sumpup', MyFirstConsumer.as_asgi()),
    path(r'v1/ws/yo/<str:uuid>/sessions', MySecondConsumer.as_asgi()),
]
```

But nothing shows up in my swagger file.

Any ideas ?

Thanks